# What are the vulnerabilities of MD5 and how can they be remedied?

Tags: cryptography, md5, hash-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If MD5 is broken, what is a better solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768913/if-md5-is-broken-what-is-a-better-solution)

What are the vulnerabilities in MD5 and what are some of the remedies for it? Also, what ares some of the concerns that a non-technical person should have and what are some of the concerns that a technical person should have as it relates to MD5?

Comment: Same as [If MD5 is broken, what is a better solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768913/if-md5-is-broken-what-is-a-better-solution)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use MD5.  Use SHA-2 (or higher) instead.

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5):

US-CERT of the U. S. Department of Homeland Security said MD5 "*should be considered cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use*,..." and most U.S. government applications will be required to move to the SHA-2 family of hash functions after 2010.

[MD5 considered harmful today](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/)

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend. The same article includes why (not collision resistant) and some of the (partial) remedies (using a salt for password hashing).

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is broken because it fails being a cryptographic hash. Specifically, it does not any longer have *second preimage resistance* Suppose we have

```
h = MD5(d)
```

where `d` is a document and `h` is the MD5-hash of it. I can now find `d1` such that `MD5(d1) = h`. This means I can find a second preimage that claims to have the same hash. Worse, I can make a document and alter hidden parts of it until I get the same hash.

The implications are that I can feed you a false document and your hash-check will believe it to be the original.

MD5 is still a trapdoor in the sense that you can't reconstruct `d` from just `h`. It has been used as such for password encryption *but you must never ever do that*. For key derivation for passwords, you should either use PBKDF2, bcrypt, or (preferably) scrypt.

SHA1 has dents in the sarcophagus as well. Which is why the SHA-2 or higher hash functions are to be chosen.