# Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index has maximum length of 1000 bytes

Tags: sql-server, key

I transfer a db script from a 64 bit system to a 32 bit system. When I execute the script it gives me the following error,

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index
>   'UQ__Users__7E800015145C0A3F' has maximum length of 1000 bytes. For
>   some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will
>   fail.

Google results and Stack Overflow questions did not help to solve this problem.

Comment: Please specify what DBMS you are using?

Comment: sql express server 10.50.2500

Comment: possible duplicate of [900 byte index size limit in character length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717317/900-byte-index-size-limit-in-character-length)

Comment: I solved this by altering `NVARCHAR(512)` to `NVARCHAR(450)`, since in my case, 2 * SIZE = 2 * 450 = 900 bytes. But, it was only limited because I supplied `UNIQUE` to that field.

Comment: great solution. an aside as of sql server 2016 sha1 is deprecated and should sha2_256 or sha2_512 according microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 12):

> For indexing columns that have Large sizes ,sqlserver indexes only
>   columns that have size up to 900 bytes.

To solve this problem

Firstly : I added a column hashCol  to generate hashcode of Type SHA1 for MyCol

```
alter table myTable
    add 
    hashCol AS HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(VARCHAR(90), MyCol))
```

Secondly : I added a unique constrain for hashCol to uniquely  Identify  MyCol

```
 ALTER  TABLE  myTable
     ADD CONSTRAINT hashCol_Unique UNIQUE (hashCol)
```

By this way I overcame the problem of Indexing columns that have large size

references

[Generate Unique hash for a field in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952213/generate-unique-hash-for-a-field-) in-sql-server

Comment: Got an error "Column 'HashCol' in table 'MyTable' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key because it is non-deterministic.". How to fix it?

Comment: To make sure the indexing works, I would rather do the following:
hashCol as convert(varchar(100), hashbytes('SHA1', MyCol), 2) persisted not null

Comment: This is okay but be sure to check that this approach doesn't generate collisions in your database which happened to me.

Answer (score 4):

Storage length of the varchar type will be +2.

**Solution**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name varchar(255)
```

so try to reduce the column length to 255 character and try indexing.

Comment: ...or reduce to to varchar(900) if you are able to do so without truncating field data.

Answer (score 2):

The combined length of all the columns should be less than 900.

```
-- make combined colum length(to be indexed / add constrains) less <= 900
ALTER TABLE tabbleName ALTER COLUMN col1 VARCHAR (500) NULL;
ALTER TABLE tabbleName ALTER COLUMN col2 VARCHAR (200) NULL;
ALTER TABLE tabbleName ALTER COLUMN col3 VARCHAR (200) NULL;
-- Then add the index
ALTER TABLE tabbleName ADD CONSTRAINT uck UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3);
```