# Uncrypt and decrypt password

Tags: jpasswordfield

I have a frame where people can login, and I have another frame where an admin can add a user (employee). I know how to encrypt the passwords (given in a jPasswordField) when adding a user using MD5 hash and what not.. But I dont know how to uncrypt it. I've googled my eyes out today but did not found a solution.

(For the sake of keeping this thread organised I've posted the code in a codepaste item).

Login frame:
http://codepaste.net/j6imgd

Addframe:
http://codepaste.net/v4744v

If someone can help me, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes such as MD5 (and I hope you aren't using plain MD5 for password storage) are one-way.

What you want to do is to simply compare the hash of the user's password to whatever they entered.

If the user's password is "kitten" and - for the time being let's imagine you're using MD5, which isn't secure - you've stored its hash, "6da89cd09ab7937478a1d47d20938536" in your user database, you'll just need to check that the hash of the password the user enters while logging in matches that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So if I understand correctly MD5 hashes are very easy to decrypt? Is it also that you can easily recognize MD5 hashes?

Comment: You can't easily reverse a MD5 password (you shouldn't use MD5) you would need to create a rainbow table to check. What you also want to do is add a salt to your password to make it more secure. The problem with MD5 is there have been known collisions. Please see my answer for a better description and link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MD5 is one-way encryption. If you want to make password decrypt-able, you should use other algorithms for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 0):

As a hash, do not use MD5. MD5 has been broken and if an attacker gets hold of your hashes he will be able to work out what the clear-text passwords are. There are techniques to make plain hash algorithms more secure (such as using salt) but MD5 is simply too broken for that.

So yes, use a hash, which is a one-way encryption (i.e. you can't decrypt it) for your passwords. You don't need to decrypt them because if the user enters the correct password it will produce the same hash.

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768913/if-md5-is-broken-what-is-a-better-solution) that discusses alternatives to MD5.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: [How to build a login system.](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

What you would want to do is hash the users password, store this in the database, then when the user comes to login in you hash the password they entered and compare it to the one stored in the database. If they match the password is the same. Please note that you shouldn't use MD5 think about using SHA 512 with a salt as show in the link above, this is what I used and it's a very useful description.